# Get Value from JSON using JArray

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I have the following string (json format)
I have gotten from my server:

```
{[{"ruta": "1","division": "7"},{"ruta": "2","division": "7"},{"ruta": "3","division":"7"},{"ruta": "4","division": "7"},{"ruta": "5","division": "7"},{"ruta": "23","division": "7"}]}
```

I want to get each value and save them in string variables in order to save them in a data base.

For that I am trying to do as follows:

```
JArray jarr = JArray.Parse(result);
foreach (JObject content in jarr.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
    {
         string tempValue = prop.Value.ToString; // This is not allowed 
         //here more code in order to save in a database
    }
}
```

But I can't find the way to convert the values to string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ToString()`, not `ToString`.

`ToString()` is a method call; `ToString` is a reference to the `ToString` method, and can only be assigned to a compatible delegate.

You can also cast to `String`, since the `JToken` class defines a conversion:

```
string tempValue = (string)prop.Value;
```

Another option to consider is to use JSON serialization: create a class that represents the JSON data (with the same structure), and deserialize the JSON to this class. It makes the code much more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 7):

You can directly de serialize your json using C# class(using:-  http://json2csharp.com/) and not need to iterate through Json.

```
public class YourClass
{
  public string ruta { get; set; }
  public string division { get; set; }
}
```

You can de serialize

```
List<YourClass> yourClasslist= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourClass>>(result.ToString());
```

You can do this because your Json is in structured format

Comment: That website is hecking awesome! It has saved my neck :)

Answer (score 5):

```
JArray jarr = JArray.Parse(result);
foreach (JObject content in jarr.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
    {
         string tempValue = prop.Value.ToString(); // This is not allowed 
         //here more code in order to save in a database
    }
}
```

as for the JSON you should start from a JObject since it's surrounded by { }, or remove them from around the JSON you posted in your question

Answer (score 1):

`JProperty.Value` is of type `JToken` which has a method `ToString` (and not a property).

See documentation [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString.htm).

The syntax should be like that:

```
string tempValue = prop.Value.ToString();
```