# JObject.Parse throws error on valid Json

Tags: json.net

Searching on `'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', ...'` finds at least 3 SO questions all of which were traced to invalid Json.

I've tried 3 different validators on:

```
[{"Imported": "This registration imported on: 06/20/2016"},{"ContactInfoUpdated": " Street Address2: Suite 222   to  Shipping Address2:   "}]
```

and all three report it as valid. And yet the runtime error tosses that same *'Additional text encountered...'*:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserComments))
{
    JToken addresses;
    addresses = JObject.Parse(UserComments).GetValue("CarbonCopy"); //errors here
    if (!ReferenceEquals(null, addresses))
    {
      //stuff
    }
}
```

To establish that there are no unintended characters after the json closes, here's the sql:

```
UPDATE dbo.[Order] SET UserComments = '[{"Imported": "This registration imported on: 06/20/2016"},{"ContactInfoUpdated": " Street Address2: Suite 222   to  Shipping Address2:   "}]' WHERE idOrder =121050
```

Comment: Your JSON *is* valid, however it represents an array of two objects, not a single object.  Consequently, `JObject.Parse` cannot be used to parse it.  Try using `JArray.Parse` or `JToken.Parse` instead.  You'll likely need to make other adjustments to your code as well; it seems like you're expecting a single object containing a value called "CarbonCopy" but what you have is two objects and neither one have that property.  It's not entirely clear from your question what you're really trying to do here.

Comment: Just really trying to avoid that error -- appreciate the re-direction.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Brian's prompting I found this post to be very helpful:

[Get Value from JSON using JArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095507/get-value-from-json-using-jarray)

My json is somewhat unusual in that it's an array of dissimilar objects. Instead of a series of name/value pair where **Name** stays constant, my 'UserComments' field contains pairs where **Name** can be '*ProfileWasEdited*', '*CCRequested*', '*Feedback*', and so on.

In order to accommodate that type of structure I need to test against the **Name** property:

```
var fields = JToken.Parse(UserComments);
var isCC = "";
foreach (JObject content in fields.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
    {
        if (prop.Name == "CarbonCopy")
        isCC = prop.Value.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Resharper informs me that I can Linq-ize the above to:

```
foreach (JProperty prop in fields.Children<JObject>().SelectMany(content => content.Properties().Where(prop => prop.Name == "CarbonCopy")))
{
    isCC = prop.Value.ToString();
}
```